# Not able to read streaming files using Spark structured streaming

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a set of CSV files which needs to be read through Spark structured streaming. After creating a `DataFrame` I need to load into a Hive table.

When a file is already present before running code through `spark-submit`,the data is loaded into Hive successfully.But when I add new CSV files on runtime, it's not at all inserting it into Hive.

Code is:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark SQL Example").config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://hostname:port").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", true)
import spark.implicits._  

val df = spark.readStream.option("header", true).csv("file:///folder path/")
val query = df.writeStream.queryName("tab").format("memory").outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).start()
spark.sql("insert into hivetab select * from tab").show()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Am I missing out something here?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: have u got any solution ? i am facing same issue... please help